# How do I split the text in a column with a special character "@"?

Tags: python, pandas, split

[image]

I am trying to separate the text before "@" in 1 column and the time after the "@" in another column.

P.S New to Python programming

I tried using the split function.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for values before `@` in `col1` and after in `col2`:

```
df['col11'] = df['col1'].str.extract('(.*)@', expand=False)

df['col22'] = df['col2'].str.extract('@(.*)', expand=False)
```

Or use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with select first or last splitted values:

```
df['col11'] = df['col1'].str.split('@').str[0]

df['col22'] = df['col2'].str.split('@').str[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar code:

```
df['col_split'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: x.split('@))
```

or:

```
import re
df['col_split'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: re.split('@', x))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).